# How does Dart run asynchronous code like Future and Stream if is single thread?

Tags: dart, stream, future

I'm having some trouble understanding Dart asynchronous programming.
According to documentation, Dart is single-threaded, so it only has one thread, which they call Isolate.

Now, we can create a new Isolate, and I understand is basically a "thread" without shared memory and/or code

What I don't understand is how Futures and Streams actually works under the hood: do they spawn a new Isolate and then send a massage with the result to the main Isolate?
If not, how is it possible to execute these asynchronous codes without blocking or lowering down the performance of the entire Isolate? Do they execute "a bit at a time" within the event loop?

Comment: It depends on how the asynchronous operation is implemented.  That asynchronous operation could involve spawning another Dart isolate, could involve calling into the Dart VM/runtime or into some FFI code to spawn a new OS thread, could involve waiting on asynchronous I/O, could involve starting another process, or might not even involve any parallelism at all.  The `Future` itself doesn't know or care; it's just a mechanism to notify callers waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete.

Comment: So can I say that Dart is single thread because the programmer can't actually create a new thread (not a new isolate), but in reality the code inside an async method is, generally speaking, managed outside the main isolate?

Comment: A Dart *isolate* runs *Dart* code in a single thread of execution.  The program as a whole *might* involve multiple threads, processes, etc.  I wouldn't say that an async function generally is managed outside the main isolate; you could have an async function that does most of its work in the main isolate but that is asynchronous only because it depends on a small part that is also asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to event programing on single thread runtimes is *Event Loops* and is what Dart VM uses.

Some more information:

- [MDN Event Loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop)
- [Wikipedia Event Loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)
- [Dart Event Loops](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a)